# Page permalink rewrite

Tags: categories, php, rewrite-rules

I added the following code which allows categories on my 'Page' post type.

```
add_action('init', 'edit_page_type');
function edit_page_type() 
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');
}
```

Now i realize the permalinks dont exactly match... How can i rewrite the page permalinks to act like the post permalinks? (which include the category before the page title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just use Posts thats was they're designed for.

You don't really categorise pages you structure them so they have parents and so on.

Comment: Ya, i understand what the differences are for. But i NEED a post type that allows `menu_order` and i couldnt figure out how to selectively order posts

Comment: figured it out the custom post order. ill just go with this solution. http://kovshenin.com/archives/customize-posts-order-in-wordpress-via-custom-fields/

Comment: You could set up a custom post type which supports order.

Comment: I had that setup, but i need to use the plugin 'Wishlist Member' (which integrates an advanced user-based time clock for activating content etc) and this isnt supported with custom post type! A lot of code i wrote for no reason! :P